# How do I compare Boost Geometries?

Tags: boost-geometry

I have 2 of these
boost::geometry::model::ring
and I am trying to tell if they are the same.
Is there a built in boost geometry compare function/method that can figure this out for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::geometry::equals(a,b)` reports if two geometries are spatially equal