# removing duplicates: How do I write a sort predicate for boost::geometry::box?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I use `boost::geometry::model::box` in a class like this:

```
struct Feature {
    typedef boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::box<point> box;

    box bounds;
    //... other members ...
};

std::list<Feature> v;
```

and I want to remove duplicates in `v`.

Normally I'd write a sort predicate so that I can do this:

```
v.sort(sort_pred);    //?
std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I'm able to use `boost::geometry::equals` (as described in [How do I compare Boost Geometries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281336/how-do-i-compare-boost-geometries)) to write `operator==`, so `std::unique` works.  Is there a similar function I can use to write the predicate to `sort`, or do I need to write one from scratch?

Alternatively, is there a better way in `boost::geometry` to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't re-use anything from `boost::geometry::index` as (sadly) the results of even a `nearest()` query is not ordered.

So, here you go with my ... simplest take on it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4505240bcec6a40c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
// #include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;

typedef bgm::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bgm::box<point> box;

namespace std {
    // less
    template <> struct less<point> {
        bool operator()(point const& a, point const& b) const { return std::tie(a.get<0>(), a.get<1>()) < std::tie(b.get<0>(), b.get<1>()); }
    };
    template <> struct less<box> {
        bool operator()(box const& a, box const& b) const { return 
                std::tie(a.min_corner().get<0>(), a.min_corner().get<1>(), a.max_corner().get<0>(), a.max_corner().get<1>())
              < std::tie(b.min_corner().get<0>(), b.min_corner().get<1>(), b.max_corner().get<0>(), b.max_corner().get<1>()); }
    };
    // equal_to
    template <> struct equal_to<point> {
        bool operator()(point const& a, point const& b) const { return std::tie(a.get<0>(), a.get<1>()) == std::tie(b.get<0>(), b.get<1>()); }
    };
    template <> struct equal_to<box> {
        bool operator()(box const& a, box const& b) const { return 
                std::tie(a.min_corner().get<0>(), a.min_corner().get<1>(), a.max_corner().get<0>(), a.max_corner().get<1>())
             == std::tie(b.min_corner().get<0>(), b.min_corner().get<1>(), b.max_corner().get<0>(), b.max_corner().get<1>()); }
    };
}

struct Feature {
    box bounds;
    //... other members ...
    std::string other;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Feature const& f) {
        return os << "{" << bg::wkt(f.bounds) << ", " << std::quoted(f.other) << "}";
    }

    struct less_by_box : std::less<box> {
        bool operator()(Feature const& a, Feature const& b) const { return std::less<box>::operator()(a.bounds, b.bounds); }
    };
    struct by_box : std::equal_to<box> {
        bool operator()(Feature const& a, Feature const& b) const { return std::equal_to<box>::operator()(a.bounds, b.bounds); }
    };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Feature> v {
        { box { {2,3}, {4,5} }, "three" },
        { box { {1,2}, {3,4} }, "two" },
        { box { {2,3}, {4,5} }, "one" },
    };

    auto dump = [&] {
        std::cout << "Size: " << v.size() << "\n";
        for (Feature const& f : v) { std::cout << f << "\n"; }
    };

    dump();

    std::cout << " -- Sort, Unique, Erase:\n";
    std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Feature::less_by_box{});
    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), Feature::by_box{}), v.end());

    dump();
}
```

Prints

```
Size: 3
{POLYGON((2 3,2 5,4 5,4 3,2 3)), "three"}
{POLYGON((1 2,1 4,3 4,3 2,1 2)), "two"}
{POLYGON((2 3,2 5,4 5,4 3,2 3)), "one"}
 -- Sort, Unique, Erase:
Size: 2
{POLYGON((1 2,1 4,3 4,3 2,1 2)), "two"}
{POLYGON((2 3,2 5,4 5,4 3,2 3)), "three"}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I eventually did, except I haven't read up on std::tie so mine was even more verbose...